# Synchronize CSS animation after dynamic displaying with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, animation, synchronization

As you see some box elements are hidden. After clicking the button all box elements will be displayed. The backgrounds are animated. Unfortunately the animations start from the beginn after displaying with jQuery them.

Is there a way to synchronize them somehow?

Here is an example:

```
.box:nth-child(n+3) {
   display: none;
}
.box {
   display: block;
   width: 200px;
   height: 50px;
   background: linear-gradient(337deg, rgba(31,212,166,1), rgba(24,54,141,1), rgba(102,24,141,1));
   background-size: 400% 400%;
   animation: AnimationName 4s ease infinite;
   margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
    $('.box:nth-child(n+3)').css('display', 'block')
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/boLgvcc8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the height of the third element to 0px and then on click you can just set it back to 50 with .css('height', '50px');